# RDS very slow and storage incosistencies

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

A couple of hours ago one of our AWS EC2 instances spike in CPU usage to 90 - 100%.

That server, along with several other production servers, use one main RDS instance for the databases.

All server instances accessing that RDS instance are non-responsive.

Here is an error that occurs several times (if not hundreds) from the sql logs on AWS:

```
140908 21:00:28 [ERROR] /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld: Sort aborted: Error writing file '/rdsdbdata/tmp/MYrOqeNU' (Errcode: 28)
```

I researched the error code and was told it meant storage issues, so we checked the monitor and it kept going from 10GB to < 1GB apparently. This doesn't make sense to me unless for some reason tmp files in the size of GB's are being messed around with.

Also the following MySQL command turns up about 28 processes (once over a hundred):

```
show processlist;
```

I really am not a DBA and feel stuck. I will provide any more information that I can upon request.

Comment: None of us know the details of how AWS has its RDS product configured. Likewise, you likely do not have the level of access to the RDS host needed to troubleshoot and resolve the problem. So - this question needs to be addressed to AWS Support (whom are very good, IMHO).

Comment: Okay, yeah the only access I have currently seems to be a SQL shell using 'mysql -u username - p pass'  etc..

Comment: Right. AWS Support are likely the only folks that will be able to get any meaningful data off of the system.

Comment: So, does that mean my only solution for this situation is to purchase a rather expensive technical support package?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. If you're using AWS for anything critical, it's well worth the money.

Comment: Try posting on the AWS forums, you can get free support there (albeit with quite a delay), or you could try just replacing the RDS instance with a new one, create a read replica then promote it to a stand alone instance and see if that resolves your issues. http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/10/11/amazon-rds-mysql-rr-promotion/

Comment: Thanks for all of your responses, I have taken your advice and signed up for the technical support plan. Also, I have the solution which I will post, which is sort of embarrassing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ends up that it was indeed a lack of storage space on the instance that hosts RDS. The **error code 28 that MySQL threw was accurate**. The SQL processes just kept backing up as there was no storage left. We also had a query that one site was executing that was quite inefficient - it took over one minute to execute. This query may have been propagating the whole issue (for some reason or another that I don't know).

We did not have any alarms set to that instance, hence we weren't able to adjust the storage space until after all of our production sites grinded to a halt.

We just **doubled the storage space and used the "Apply Immediately"** option and waited ~ 1 to 2 hours. After that, there was plenty of storage space for everything to continue operating smoothly. We also made sure to set alarms on all of our RDS instances...